# JmsOutboundGateway Error: No sender waiting for reply

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

We run a sequence of around 80 batch jobs with more than half partitioned with up to 50 partitions. As far as I can tell, the only non-standard thing we do is to disable auto-startup. The gateway is start and stop are managed by step listener. This is fine for the majority of time but we are seeing an occasional failure. I increased the logging and see all messages sent out with the correlationId. The stack trace happens after the remote partitions end (in this case ...about 3 minutes) :

```
2016-01-19 22:19:01,517 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway] (springbatch.partitioned.jms.taskExecutor-38) policy.estimatepayroll.outbound-gateway Sending message with correlationId d1025dfd-3551-4df8-96a7-043364c52e3d_18


2016-01-19 22:21:55,240 WARN  [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway] (org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway#0.replyListener-1) Failed to consume reply with correlationId d1025dfd-3551-4df8-96a7-043364c52e3d_18
    java.lang.RuntimeException: No sender waiting for reply
        at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.onMessage(JmsOutboundGateway.java:945)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:326)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1069)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1061)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:958)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The problem is that when this happens, the onMessage() method throws a RuntimeException which kills the thread. Subsequent jobs have less threads to use and as a result some partitions execute in series instead of parallel.

I have reviewed the code and can't find how this problem can occur? Could it be because the replies is a HashMap and not thread safe?

Thanks for any help / suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is the `receive-timeout` is too low - so the sending thread times out and is no longer waiting for the reply.

The default timeout is quite low (5 seconds).

**EDIT**

Sorry, forgot that this was recently fixed (in 4.2 and 4.1).

We've back-ported but not yet released 4.0.x or 3.0.x with the fix.

[JIRA Here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3885).

Comment: should be set to this

policy.estimatepayroll.partitioned.timeout=500000000

in both the outbound gateway receive-timeout and the partition handler

Comment: Sorry - didn't read your last paragraph properly. We recently fixed that.

Comment: we are on spring batch 2.2.7 and spring integration 2.2.6

I assume you fixed in a new version. Can I easily migrate to my code base?

Comment: Yikes - we didn't backport all the way back to 2.2.x. I edited the answer with the versions. Batch 2.2.x will probably work with 3.0.x but we haven't released 3.0.9 with the fix yet. We can do so and/or backport back to 2.2.x as well)

Comment: Thanks for your support and extremely timely responses

Comment: I backported the fix; [PR here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1695). When it's merged we can build 2.2.7.

Comment: The fix is on master but we haven't built that branch for a couple of years now and it seems some incompatibilities with the build system have crept in. Watch this space.

Comment: sorry to be a pest but any timeframe on this release ?  Is there a way I can access with a build file and build locally?

Comment: We just pushed 2.2.7 to maven central; it doesn't show up in search.maven.org yet (it usually takes a few hours), but [according to bintray](https://bintray.com/spring/jars/org.springframework.integration/2.2.7.RELEASE/view#central) it was synced ok with maven central. If you can't get it from maven central you can get it from `http://repo.spring.io/release`